# Basic MVC principles using Express.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, express

**express.js** provides you with a decent barebone system to implement a standard **MVC** development pattern. However most tutorials i've seen apply controller logic in a routes file or a global app file.

In an ideal world:

**Model** - Manages fundamental behaviours and data

**Controller** - Sends commands to the model and the view

**View** - Renders data from the model

---

currently i have the following:

*routes/index.js* - route pointing to an action

```
router.get('/hotels', function(req, res, next) {
    hotels.run(req, res, next);
    next();
});
```

*controllers/hotels.js* - controller sending a command to a model

```
module.exports = {
    run: function(req, res, next) {
        var users = new require('../models/hotels');
        users.run(function(callback) {
            res.render('hotels', { title: 'Hotels page', users: callback });
        }); 
    }
}
```

*models/hotel.js* - model requesting data

```
module.exports = {
    run: function(callback) {
        connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
            callback(rows);
            //console.log(rows);
        });
    }
}
```

No matter what i try, i can't get the data from the model to return to the controller to then be passed to the view. I understand there are probably multiple errors within the above code as i'm new to express. But the fundamentals should be ok, and i'm hoping it's something obvious as to why i can't return the model data,as all logic above other than the callback works.

Comment: In your route, you're opening the possibility of executing `next` twice because you passed it to the controller, and then executed it on the following line. Do one or the other, not both. I would also simplify your routes to `router.get('/hotels', hotels.run)`

Comment: thanks for the tip @KevinB will amend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe i have solved this issue, if people are looking to use a similar MVC approach on an express.js project.

*routes.js* - changed to match Kevin's cleaner method.

```
router.get('/hotels', hotels.run);
```

*controller/hotels.js* -

```
module.exports = {
    run: function(req, res, next) {
        var users = new require('../models/hotels');
        users.run(function(err, callback) {
            res.render('hotels', { title: 'Hotels page', users: callback });
        });
    }
}
```

*models/hotel.js*

```
module.exports = {
    run: function(callback) {
        connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
            callback(err, rows);
        });
    }
}
```

so now the model returns the query as requested by the controller, giving the controller the ability to pass the data to the view.